# Remove whitespace in output HTML code

Tags: coldfusion, whitespace

Consider test.cfm file with the following content:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <cfif foo EQ bar>
            <cfset test = "something" />
        </cfif>
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When run in the browser, the source code of the output of this file will look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>



        <p>Hello!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix this?

There's nothing to *fix* - the HTML is perfectly valid and functional.

If your issue is the size of request, use gzip encoding.

If your issue is reading the source for debugging/etc, use developer tools such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)/etc.

However, general things you should be doing to improve maintainability (which at the same time also reduces whitespace output) are:

1) Move anything that isn't display logic out of your views.

2) Convert display logic to functions and custom tags as appropriate, which both make it easier to prevent/control output.

To prevent unwanted content being output, you can:

- Wrap the entire section in [cfsilent](http://cfdocs.org/cfsilent), to ensure nothing gets output.
- Enable `enablecfoutputonly` attribute of [cfsetting](http://cfdocs.org/cfsetting) then only use cfoutput around things you want to be output.
- Always set `output=false` on component and function tags.
- When you want to selectively output some text, wrap non-tag non-output segments in CFML comments `<!---`...`--->` (e.g. useful for preventing newline output in custom tags)

(I never bother with cfprocessingdirective, everything mentioned above solves the issues better.)

Comment: 1) Of course all the "business logic" goes into CFC's functions, but I still have to invoke them somehow in the CFMs, don't I?

// I will look into gzip encoding, which I think will be the most efficient way to do this...

Comment: You're confusing terms. Business logic goes where it needs to go. Display logic is when you need to control how your views are displayed - can go in CFCs/functions, but sometimes makes more sense in custom tags/whatever - depends what it's doing.

Comment: I think CF9 or CF10 has an admin setting for gzip, but couldn't find anything about it in a quick search. (I know [Railo](http://getrailo.org) has such a setting.)

Comment: Thanks for lot's of useful information. I still have to do some research and see what fits me best.

Comment: http://cfbestpractices.blogspot.ca/2012/03/understand-what-generates-whitespace.html?m=1

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the CF Administrator, there is an option to suppress white space.

It is under 'Server Settings' --> 'Settings' its called 'Enable Whitespace Management'.

Answer (score 4):

Try `<cfprocessingdirective suppressWhiteSpace="true">`

Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-76de.html

Comment: Works but... Is there a way to make it global and not having to put it in every file? Maybe something in Application.cfc?

Comment: Also investigate <cfsilent> and <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
If you want more selective control over output but tptcat's answer addresses whitespace as a whole.

Comment: Check out Ben Nadel's great Application.cfc guide here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm

If you want to wrap the `cfprocessingdirective` around every call you should be able to in OnRequest.

Also, as @BenKoshy said, you can get finer control over this with the two tags he mentioned.